# Login example MFC

Tags: authentication, mfc

This is a very simple task. I just want to get a username and password from the user. If the username is admin and the password is password then on clicking the ok button should call the next dialog. If the username and password is something else then a message box should appear saying Invalid login. My problem is, even if I give the username as admin and password as password I am getting Invalid login message box. Here is my code.

```
void CUserLoginDlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{
CString uname="admin";
CString pwd="password";
if(m_Username== uname|| m_Password==pwd)
{   
    CDisk Dlg;
    Dlg.DoModal();
}
else
{
    AfxMessageBox("Invalid Login");
}
}
```

Even if I give the login credentials as admin and password, I am getting the Messagebox. I dont know how to solve this. Pls help me on this.

Comment: Where do you set m_Username and m_Password? Post enough code that we can help you!

Comment: m_Username and m_Password are the CString variables for username and password editboxes. They are declared in the dialog header file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a corrected version:

```
void CUserLoginDlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{
  UpdateData();  // updates m_Username and m_Password

  CString uname="admin";
  CString pwd="password";

  if (m_Username == uname && m_Password == pwd)
  {                   // ^ replaced || by &&
     CDisk Dlg;
     Dlg.DoModal();
   }
   else
   {
     AfxMessageBox("Invalid Login");
   }
}
```

You must call [UpdataData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/t9fb9hww.aspx) at the beginning of your function.

And your test `m_Username == uname || m_Password == pwd` is wrong. The explanation is left as an exercise for the reader.